# How to fix checkReleaseBuilds false when generate build apk in Android Studio v3.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I develop one android application in **Android studio v3.1.1**.
My project has finished and I want **generate apk** from **Build -> Generate Build Apk** but after second show me below error in `Logcat` :

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
```

How can I fix it? Please help me

Comment: havew you tried to do just what it suggests?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following `lintOptions` block in your app's `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    lintOptions {
        // Returns whether lint should be quiet (for example, not write informational messages such as paths to report files written)
        quiet true

        // Whether lint should set the exit code of the process if errors are found
        abortOnError false

        // Returns whether lint will only check for errors (ignoring warnings)
        ignoreWarnings true

        // Returns whether lint should check for fatal errors during release builds. Default is true.
        // If issues with severity "fatal" are found, the release build is aborted.
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The message you've been given tells you everything you need to know. Either fix the lint errors that are causing this message (check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#commandline) to see how to run lint and where to find the full report with details), or add `checkReleaseBuilds false` to the `lintOptions` block in your build.gradle file.

Comment: can you send to me code for fix it? please. I am amateur

Comment: I'm not sure how much more information I can give you. Check the link in my answer for detailed instructions on checking for lint errors. Or, open the build.gradle file in your project, and add exactly what the error message tells you to add.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lintOptions block in your app's build.gradle

```
 lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
  }
```